# How to preserve line breaks in Scriptaculous InPlaceEditor?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, scriptaculous, inplace-editing

I have a page with various textareas which can be edited using **Scriptaculous** (is there a better option?):

```
<h4>
    <span id="someID">
        <?php echo $_SESSION['someID']; ?>
    </span>
</h4>
```

The **PHP** file looks like so:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['someID']))
$_SESSION['someID'] = "Some text which spans more than <br />one line of a textarea";
?>
```

When I click on the element and it becomes a textarea, the line breaks are present. However, when the textarea loses focus and goes back to being whatever element it was, the line breaks are lost.

Is there a way to preserve the line breaks? Should I be somehow using `\n` instead of `<br />`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exacly - in `<textarea>` break line tag `<br/>` is treated as a text.

If you change it to `\r\n` it will works.

Why additional `\r` ? For example in Windows/IE/etc simple `\n` is not enough. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not quite that simple. The content from the PHP file originally appears as text (so needs `<br />` - it is only when the element is clicked that it turns into a textarea.

Comment: Why ? During the click event you change this `<p>` into `<textarea>`. Do some text replace here too and it'll works.

Comment: I don't really understand this, sorry. The click event is already bound to Scriptaculous. Are you saying I should be doing something like: `$('#someID').live('click', function() {var content = $(this).html(); content = content.replace("<br />", "\r\n") });`